# how add custom field in "Order Summary" checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout

How I can add custom field with custom value in Order Summary? ty for answer
[image]

Comment: is it static field or dynamic ?

Comment: @BornCoder custom field static, value = dynamic

Comment: Create field in admin system.xml and use that field here, so that you will get dynamic value. If you  have any requirement depend on checkout page then you need create attribute for checkout page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to explain. It's not just add field in checkout, you also need to add this field to admin order, invoice, shipment, creditmemo.

There are so many files and coding involve in adding just one field in order summery.

I would suggest use SilkSoftwar Module Creator: https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2-module-creator.php

Use the option **"Need to Add New Extra Fee for Order"** and generate your module, you will get whole coding of what you want.

Hope it will help you.